# What replaces the old BlockBlobService.get_blob_to_bytes in the new BlobServiceClient?

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have an old azure function which uses BlockBlobService ->get_blob_to_bytes.
As described here: https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/storage/storage-python-how-to-use-blob-storage.md#download-blobs

I belive i need to update BlockBlobService to BlobServiceClient. But i can not find the get_blob_to_bytes in the BlobServiceClient?

```
Exception: AttributeError: 'BlobServiceClient' object has no attribute 'get_blob_to_bytes'
```

How can i get blob to bytes using the BlobServiceClient?

Edit; or do i need to use: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice.baseblobservice?view=azure-python-previous#azure-storage-blob-baseblobservice-baseblobservice-get-blob-to-bytes

Edit2; https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/migration_guide.md#storage-blob-service-sdk-migration-guide-from--2x-to-12x

[image]

i got

```
Name: azure-storage-blob
Version: 12.16.0
```

But there is no BlobClient.get_blob_to_bytes.... Or atleast not when i try it??

Edit3: To further add confusion, i 'm consuming messages from a Queue. And when instantiating a BlobClient is expects account_url, container_name and blob_name. Thats all well if you have a [container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python?tabs=managed-identity%2Croles-azure-portal%2Csign-in-azure-cli), but i have a [queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/queues/storage-python-how-to-use-queue-storage?tabs=python%2Cenvironment-variable-windows).

Anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But there is no BlobClient.get_blob_to_bytes.... Or atleast not when i try it??

Yes, like you have mentioned there is no `get_blob_to_bytes()` in `BlobClient`. However, you can get the desired results using `download_blob().readall()`.

```
from  azure.storage.blob  import  BlobClient

connection_string="<CONNECTION_STRING>"

client = BlobClient.from_connection_string(connection_string,'container','abc.txt')

blob_bytes = client.download_blob().readall()
print(blob_bytes)
```

*Results:*

[image]

---

> Edit3: To further add confusion, i 'm consuming messages from a Queue. And when instantiating a BlobClient is expects account_url, container_name and blob_name. Thats all well if you have a [container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python?tabs=managed-identity%2Croles-azure-portal%2Csign-in-azure-cli), but i have a [queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/queues/storage-python-how-to-use-queue-storage?tabs=python%2Cenvironment-variable-windows).

However, since your requirement is to get the bytes from queue use `QueueClient`. Below is something you can try to achieve your requirement.

```
from azure.storage.queue import QueueClient
import base64

connection_string="<CONNECTION_STRING>"

queue = QueueClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=connection_string, queue_name='queue')
messages = queue.receive_messages()
for message in messages:
    print(base64.b64decode(message.content).decode('utf-8').encode('utf-8'))
```

*Results:*

[image]

Comment: Thank, one followup question: In the old code there was Input_blob = BlockBlobService(
        connection_string)  and  file = input_blob.get_blob_to_bytes(
        message['in-container'], message['filename']) using some parameteres in the blob. How can i do this with the QueueClient. I actually dont understand what the logic here does, and thats a problem when i need to recreate it....

Comment: @otk Both the Blob and Queue services are different and have different sdks. Don't get confused with Blobs to Queues. Blobs do not have such thing called queues. Since your requirement was to use queue I have used `QueueClient` and not `BlobClient`. The mentioned lines of code in the comments belongs to `BlobClient` whereas in the answer I have used `QueueClient` as per the requirement.